# Group a collection by a certain criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

so I have a collection in mongoDB that has an structure like the following:

```
{
    "_id": 129flaslkfja,
    "number": 10
}
```

in this collection some elements have the number field set to 1 others to 2, others to 3, etc. in random order. I want to get an array that has in the first position all models with the number 1 in the next position all the models with the number  2 and so on. I know I can do this with a loop and a simple find or where but I want to know if there's a simpler, cleaner and more effective way in terms of performance.

I have tried with $group, $match but this is not what I want.

For example this is the data in my database:

```
[{
  "_id": a1,
  "number": 1
},
{
  "_id": a2,
  "number": 3
},
{
  "_id": a3,
  "number": 2
},
{
  "_id": a4,
  "number": 2
},
{
  "_id": a5,
  "number": 2
},
{
  "_id": a6,
  "number": 1
}]
```

So I want to group by number value like this:

```
[
    [{
      "_id": a1,
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": a6,
      "number": 1
    }],

    [{
      "_id": a3,
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": a4,
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": a5,
      "number": 2
    }],

    [{
      "_id": a2,
      "number": 3
    }]
]
```

Comment: Wha?  Try this;  edit and add 2 or three more input docs (they're small) and show an example of you'd like the output document to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try below code

```
original_list.group_by(&:number).values
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can do:

```
original_list.group_by {|x| x[:number]}.values
```

It's not clear if you were asking for a Ruby solution, though.